# Javascript works in all browser exept IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

When I click a button, with the onClick function, I replace an image with another one.
The code is this

```
<a class="blue_button" onClick="javascript:loading.style.display='block';zip.style.visibility='hidden';"
href="javascript:getsupport('zip')" id="download">
<img id="zip" src="img/zip.png">
<img id="loading" src="img/loading.gif">
</a>
```

in the css I have this:

```
    .blue_button{
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    width:110px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:12px;
        border-radius:4px;
        padding:0 23px 0 20px;
    }

        .blue_button img{
            position:relative;


top:5px;
        margin-right:7px;
    }

    .blue_button img#loading{
        display:none;
        float:left;
        top:-17px;
    }
```

it works in every browsers, exept IE9. If I active the Compatibility mode it works, but I need to maintain the standard mode.

== SOLVED ==
using unobtrusive js. Thanks to all

```
window.onload = loading;
function loading()
{
    document.getElementById('download').onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('zip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any errors occurring on the page?

Comment: I would like to see a HTML page too, and what does getsupport do? You have both an onclick and a href with javascript. Also the onclick includes "javascript:" that could be the error.

Comment: Maybe use document.getElementById() ?

Comment: It's OK but pointless to have an "onclick" attribute value begin with "javascript:".  This should not work in Firefox; the code makes the assumption that it can access DOM elements as global variables based on "id" values, which is a non-standard Internet Explorer convention not supported in Firefox.

Comment: Oh yes also having both an "href" and an "onclick" is a pretty bad idea.  The code should really be gathered up in a function.

Comment: Your code is in the style of a webpage written in 1999. Learn how to add events with unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: Where have you learnt JavaScript? This code style (`onClick` instead of `onclick`, `javascript:` pseudoprotocol, intrusive script/style, etc) seems to stem off from a prehistoric tutorial/resource. Please ensure that the resources which you're consulting is created or updated no longer than one year ago or so.

Comment: where is the code for `getsupport('zip')`?

Comment: solved with Unobtrusive JavaScript!

Comment: See my post for just that - and more

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem:

```
onClick="javascript:loading.style.display='block';zip.style.visibility='hidden';"
```

the onclick event does not need the `javascript:`

If you included rest of the JavaScript, I might be able to test it.

Also you have both the onclick and href. You might want to just use one of them. You might want to have a look at `addEventListener()` you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

On another note your CSS class naming is pretty bad. You don't want to call them things like blue, red ect. that could be changed. You want to keep them semantic.

Read: [What Makes For a Semantic Class Name?](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/)

Answer (score 1):

youre using a object called loading. but it dont exist its a DOM id. so you need to retrive it from the page first using document.getElementById("loading") (or the querySelector).

try changing youre code to

```
onClick="document.getElementById("loading").style.display='block';onClick="document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility='hidden';"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Allan said, you have too many things going on and you are relying on side effects and scope overloading

This is how I would do it:

Plain JS

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("download").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display='block';
   // use .display='none' to remove, 
   // visibility='hidden' to hide but leave the space
    document.getElementById("zip").style.display='none'; 
    getsupport('zip');
    return false;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#download").on("click",function() {
    $("#loading").show();
    $("#zip").hide(); 
    getsupport('zip');
    return false;
  });
});
```

HTML in both cases:

```
<a class="blue_button" href="#" id="download"><img id="zip" src="img/zip.png"><img id="loading" src="img/loading.gif"></a>
```